# Правильный перенос слов: "кисонька", "кармашек", "что-то"

Tags: перенос

Как правильно перенести слова:
**кисонька, кармашек, что-то.**

Answer (score 1):

Ки-сонька, кисонь-ка,

кар-машек, карма-шек

что- - то

Comment: Людмила, не надо отвечать на такие вопросы. Это же школьное задание, а существо даже "пожалуйста" написать не потрудилось.